# iSpeech API Popup

Tags: objective-c, ios, popupwindow, ispeech

I can not figure out how to make use of the iSpeech API. I use TTS and the API actually speaks, but I would like to know how to get rid of the pop-up box that comes up when doing the Speech Synthesis, As I need other UI working while this is going on. I read online that you would need to use the REST API, but that is unsupported on mobile devices. I need a way to hide the dialog box. Any help would be nice.

Comment: The official way is to pay them. The unofficial way can be done, using some `UIWindow` APIs, but I'm not sure that I can share it.

Comment: Please share it if possible, because I have been looking everywhere and I just can't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, you go. Use it at your own risk.

```
-(void) removeISpeechPopups
{
    NSArray *windows = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows];

    for (UIWindow *window in windows)
    {
        if ([NSStringFromClass([window class]) isEqualToString:@"ISPopupBackgroundView"])
        {
            // NOTE: Morally, I wouldn't do this. Simply for development, 
            // this is fine, but don't put this in a real application, 
            // as it takes away from iSpeech's revenue at the end of the day.
            [window setHidden:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there absolutely no other way, Are there any other free TSS services??

Comment: @user1418074 nope, not really. The cost isn't that much, however, so I would invest in it personally, if it is that big of an issue.

Comment: exactly how much is it??